# How to avoid indenting images when aligning to the left?

Tags: web

What I want to do is continue to keep images on the left like my first paragraph. but it keeps indenting. Here is a reduced example to show what I have:

```
<html>
    <h3>Acknowledge the Clicker</h3>
    <p id="clicker">
    <img align="left" src="https://farm2.staticflickr.com/1139/821163889_6a1125ac98_s.jpg" HEIGHT="175" WIDTH="160"/>
    Step 1:Click and give your dog a treat or praise them<br>
    Step 2:Repeat Step 1 at least 24 more times(This is what we call"<a href="http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/Classical%20Conditioning?s=t" target="_blank"><font color="#69FFFF"><em>Classical Conditioning</em></font></a>")<br>
    IMPORTANT: <em>ALWAYS</em> give a treat or praise your dog after clicking<br>
    </p>
    <h3>Sit</h3>
    <p id="sit">
    <img align="left" src="https://farm1.staticflickr.com/23/123112077_eb473a16ac_s.jpg" HEIGHT="161" WIDTH="146"/>
    Step 1:Wait until your dog sits then click and reward/praise<br>
    Step 2:Repeat Step 1 10 times more<br>
    Step 3:So you have 2 options:<br>A.Use a hand signal to get your dog to sit<br>B.Say sit<br> which ever you decide to use do it then click and reward/praise<br>
    Step 4:Repeat Step 3 20 more times<br>
</html>
```

Comment: You should include a small example of what you have tried and why it's not good enough. Giving a link to an external page that will change or go away later would make this question useless to others.

Answer (score 0):

Removing the align="left" from your image tags will solve your problem. I've also fixed up some of your other code "slightly" to make it better:

```
<style>
    // your other styles here. I removed your sit and clicker ones
    .instructions {
    color: #9E9E9E;
    font-family: monospace;
    font-size: 15px;
    text-align: left;
    }

    .instructions .steps {
        display: inline-block;
        vertical-align: top;
    }

    .definition {
        color: #E00025; 
    }
    .definition span {
        color: #69FFFF;
        font-style: italic;
    }
</style>
```

Your HTML code:

```
<div class="instructions">
        <h3>Acknowledge the Clicker</h3>
        <img src="http://paws101.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/ClickerTraining-PaswsitiveStepsDogTraining-300x260.png" HEIGHT="175" WIDTH="160" valign="top"/>
        <div class="steps">
        Step 1:Click and give your dog a treat or praise them<br>
        Step 2:Repeat Step 1 at least 24 more times(This is what we call" <a class="definition" href="http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/Classical%20Conditioning?s=t" target="_blank"><span>Classical Conditioning</span></a>")<br>
        IMPORTANT: <em>ALWAYS</em> give a treat or praise your dog after clicking
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="instructions">  
        <h3>Sit</h3>
        <img src="http://www.kimballstock.com/pix/DOG/03/DOG_03_RK0219_02_P.JPG" HEIGHT="161" WIDTH="146" />
        <div class="steps">
        Step 1:Wait until your dog sits then click and reward/praise<br>
        Step 2:Repeat Step 1 10 times more
        Step 3:So you have 2 options:<br>
        A.Use a hand signal to get your dog to sit<br>
        B.Say sit<br>
        which ever you decide to use do it then click and reward/praise<br>
        Step 4:Repeat Step 3 20 more times<br>
        </div>
    </div>
```

One last fix is to remove your first closing head tag. The style section should be enclosed in the head section. I have left the 
 tags in your code, but I recommend removing them as it is bad coding habit in most cases.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you see the indentation is that the first image was told to float to the left. Text that comes after will attempt to float around it (including later paragraphs).

You can stop it from doing that at some point by using the `clear:both;` `css` style.  For example, to have your `Sit` heading level 3 text appear below the first picture, do this:

```
<h3 style="clear:both;">Sit</h3>
```

Alternately you could add that style to your `#sit` style if you want just the paragraph and not the header to behave that way.

For reference, [this guide](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_float.asp) is useful.